# Azure Stream analytics 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' error

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I want to store the telemetry data received at the Azure IoTHub to SQL data base through Stream analytics. But I am getting input error when i a start my streaming job. I have attached screenshot of the code, error and message received at the IoT hub.[image][image][image]
How to rectify this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rectified the error.
Mistake was in the defined JSON String.

Corrected string :

MSG_TXT = '{ {"temperature": "{temperature}","time": "{time}","date":"{date}"}}'

Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify this answer to help others thanks!